# GDPR, is scrolling the page can mean cookie acceptance?

Tags: gdpr, website

For example take a look at https://www.cookiebot.com/ as soon as you scroll down a bit, the consenting options fades away, and it puts a cookie in your browser, that you accepted their cookies.

Is this acceptable by the GDPR / ePrivacy regulation, as a cookie and tracking (analytics, fb pixel) consent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. According to GDPR consent must be:

> Consent should be given by **a clear affirmative act establishing a freely given, specific, informed and unambiguous indication of the data subject’s agreement** to the processing of personal data relating to him or her, such as by a written statement, including by electronic means, or an oral statement

Scrolling down is not a clear, affirmative, specific or unambiguous indication of consent, and therefore does not fulfill the requirements for GDPR.

Comment: This is now also officially confirmed. The European Data Protection Board has issued [Guidelines 05/2020 on consent under Regulation 2016/679](https://edpb.europa.eu/sites/edpb/files/files/file1/edpb_guidelines_202005_consent_en.pdf) which clarifies the cookie consent. In particular it fully clarifies that using "scrolling a page" and so called "cookie walls" it is not possible to obtain a valid consent under GDPR.